# jQuery not working when page loaded via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an index page that has jQuery loaded as well as a js file for a slider plugin. Then I'm using an on click event to use .load to load an external page, like this:

```
//jQuery loaded from Google CDN here (in head)

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".button" ).click(function() {
        var myUrl = "/url-to-page";
        jQuery( "#target-div" ).load(myUrl);
    });
});
```

This successfully loads the external page into #target-div, but the jQuery loaded on the index page does not fire on elements loaded from the external page. For example, I have some images (for the slider plugin) on the external page, but the slider plugin doesn't turn them into a slideshow as it would if I put those same images (inside a wrapper div) onto the index page directly.

The external page does not any html, head, or body tags--only the content I want to load wrapped in some divs.

Does anyone know the "trick" to making jQuery work on an externally loaded page?

Comment: how are you trying to address or call those elements in the other page loaded dynamically?

Comment: There is no trick -- the content from the external page didn't exist in the current page DOM when the plugins and other scripts ran to set themselves up. jQuery can't manipulate what it can't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your click event has already been bound.  You will need to bind the click events to the newly created elements on your page *after* they have been loaded.  Jquery's load method takes a function as a second parameter.  It is fired once the load is complete.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( ".button" ).click(function() {
        var myUrl = "/url-to-page";
        jQuery( "#target-div" ).load(myUrl, function () {
          // bind events here
        });
    });
});
```

**edit: using event delegation**

```
$(function () {    //shorthand for document ready
    $('#target-div').on('click', '.button', function () {
        $("#target-div").load("/url-to-page");
    });
});
```

Every `.button` within `#target-div` will have the `click` event bound to it.  The click event will also be bound to every `.button` element added to `#target-div`.  Hope this helped.

Comment: You should use [`Event Delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this, which will mean you'll only have to attach the events at load.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So using `on` will allow you to pass a second selector binding to everything (even newly added elements) within the first selector.  This fixes all of the .. async / double binding issues that could potentially arise with the above solution.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I will edit and post an example using `on` as suggested by @Jivings